# Parse Server Cloud Code background job query and update objects

Tags: javascript, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have a Parse Server app hosted on back4app and I am running a Background Job that **runs every minute** and queries the `Letters` class, where the column `deliveryDate` is less or equal to the current date, here's my **main.js** file:

```
// DELIVER A LETTER
Parse.Cloud.job("deliverLetter", function (request, status) {
    var now = new Date();
    // var nowTime = date.getTime();

    var Letters = Parse.Object.extend("Letters");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Letters);
    query.lessThanOrEqualTo("deliveryDate", now);
    query.find().then (function (objects) {
        objects.forEach(function (obj) {
            obj.set("isDelivered", true);

            Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
            obj.save(null, { useMasterKey: true } ).then(function(obj) {
                response.success(obj);
            }, function(error) {
                response.error(error)
            });
    });
});
```

So, for instance, I save a row in the Letters class where `deliveryDate` is set to yesterday, in order for me to test this Cloud Code function. There's another column called `isDelivered` and it's set to False. So, my function above should set `isDelivered` into True and update my `Letters`'s object.

But it doesn't work, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

### Edit

Thanks to `danh`, I've fixed my code as it follows:

```
var Letters = Parse.Object.extend("Letters");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Letters);
    query.lessThanOrEqualTo("deliveryDate", now);
    query.equalTo("isDelivered", false);

    query.find().then (function (objects) {
        let savePromises = objects.map(function (obj) {
            obj.set("isDelivered", true);
            return obj.save(null, { useMasterKey: true } );
        });
        Promise.all(savePromises).then(function(obj) {
            response.success(obj);
        }, function(error) {
            response.error(error)
        });
    });
```

I would need to call another function from my main.js file which sends a push notifications and needs some parameters. I usually call it from my app, how would I call it from within that above function?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("pushiOS", function(request, response) {

  var user = request.user;
  var params = request.params;
  var userObjectID = params.userObjectID
  var data = params.data

  var recipientUser = new Parse.User();
  recipientUser.id = userObjectID;

  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo("userID", userObjectID);

  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: data
  }, { success: function() {
      console.log("#### PUSH SENT!");
  }, error: function(error) {
      console.log("#### PUSH ERROR: " + error.message);
  }, useMasterKey: true});
  response.success('success');
});
```

Maybe into Promise.all()?

```
Promise.all(savePromises).then(function(obj) {
     response.success(obj);

Parse.Cloud.define("pushiOS"...

}, function(error) { 
    response.error(error)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `save()` that's in progress or not yet started when `response.success()` is called will be terminated (or won't get a chance to start). To fix, collect promises for all of the saves, and run them together with `Promise.all()`, which resolves only after all of the promises passed to it have resolved.

```
query.find().then (function (objects) {
    // Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); don't need this
    let savePromises = objects.map(function (obj) {
        obj.set("isDelivered", true);
        return obj.save(null, { useMasterKey: true } );
    });
    Promise.all(savePromises).then(function(obj) {
        response.success(obj);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });
});
```

Also, note, incidentally, that `query.lessThanOrEqualTo("deliveryDate", now);` will get all of the objects with deliveryDates before now, including the ones you processed previously.  That result will get monotonically longer over time, eventually exceeding the 1 minute between runs, or blowing some other system resource.

Maybe you really want...

```
query.lessThanOrEqualTo("deliveryDate", now);
query.equalTo("isDelivered", false);
```

**EDIT**

The second question can be handled by factoring a promise-returning push function like this...

```
function pushDataToUser(userID, data)
    var recipientUser = new Parse.User();
    recipientUser.id = userID;
    let pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.equalTo("userID", userID);
    return Parse.Push.send({ where:pushQuery, data:data });
}
```

That can be called from cloud code like this...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("pushiOS", function(request, response) {
    let params = request.params;
    pushDataToUser(params.userObjectID, params.data).then(function() {
        console.log("#### PUSH SENT!");
        response.success('success');
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("#### PUSH ERROR! " + JSON.stringify(error));
        response.error(error);
    });
}
```

...and the new promise-returning function can be added to any other promise chain like this...

```
// function doSomething() returns a promise (like from a find() or a save()
return doSomething().then(function() {
    // initialize someId and someData
    return pushDataToUser(someId, someData)
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, what is 'Promise' though? maybe you meant 'Letters'??

Comment: :-) Promise is the object that you send `then` to.  Query.find and Object.save both return promises.  And Promise.all() runs a group of them.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I see, I didn't know that, thanks, I'll give a try to your code right now ;)

Comment: Sure.  Here's a parse-specific doc...https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#promises It's my favorite part of JS that promises have made async programming so simple.  There's a more modern syntax called async-await which you should also check out.

Comment: thanks so much again, it works like a charm, I've edited my question, hopefully you may help me with a new issue as well ;) anyway, i've accepted your answer.

Comment: sure.  see edit.  that other question would also be appropriate split off into it's own question